# How does Lambda@Edge decide which region to run in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge, aws-regions

My CloudFront distribution is geo-restricted to UK only.
My WAF is blocking all non-UK traffic.
I have a Lambda@Edge function attached to my CloudFront, triggering from "origin request".

Testing this from my home in the UK: my function mostly triggers in the London region.
But sometimes it triggers in Ireland, Frankfurt, etc. regions instead.

I'm trying to understand why.
What criteria is Lambda@Edge using to decide which region to run in?
I understood it to be "the closest region to me". But seems it must be using other criteria.

(I'm not after alternative solutions here: just interested in understanding how Lambda@Edge works in this scenario)